# Downgrade C# Project from visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a visual c# 2008 windows form application ,then i edited the code in a computer which had visual studio 2010,but i can no longer run it in visual 2008,is there a way i can do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you say "can no longer run it"... what happens?

- the sln files are not compatible; you'll need different sln files for each VS version
- the csproj are *mostly* compatible, although you might see a "version 4 not recognised, using 3.5 instead" warning or two, which is usually fine
- the cs is compatible as long as you don't use `dynamic` or the other new language features

In most cases you can get away with just having a separate sln for VS2010. So just rename it to "Whatever_2010.sln", get your old "Whatever.sln" back from your source repository, and rename it to "Whatever_2008.sln".

Comment: If you want to get rid of the "tools version 4.0 not recognized" warning, you can just look for it in the .csproj files and change the "4.0" to a "3.5" by hand.

Comment: after changing Tools Version to 3.5. Visual Studio 2010 asks me to upgrade your project.. After upgrading it replaces this 3.5 with 4.0

Answer (score 8):

http://stevedunns.blogspot.com/2010/02/tool-to-switch-project-files-between.html