# How can I open a Visual Web Developer 2010 Express in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody tell me how to open a VWD 2010 Express project in Visual Studio 2005?

Answer (score 1):

Don't open the *.sln file because that simply won't work.

Easiest way I can think of is to create a new project in Visual Studio 2005, then using "Add Existing File" (R-Click the Project) add all the files that should be there.  Bear in mind you may need to create multiple projects to accomadate the previous structure.

You can see which projects you need to add by checking the solution's directory for *.csproj/*.vbproj files.

Note that the solution is incompatible for a reason, there are likely to be multiple issues whereby .Net 2 does not support the content of the likely .Net 4 code/config created in VWD2010.

It may be *much* easier for the person using VS05 to simply [download VWD2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express), which is *free*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help: [Solution Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/SolutionConverter.aspx)

I used this tool for some conversions, but I haven't tried yet what you want to do so I can't tell you for sure if it'll work...

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I installed VWD 2010 express on my serer.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring a lot about this i got same words from all and these suits as extract for them.

> Easiest way is probably to create a new project in VS 2005, and use
>   the add existing item dialog to add the code to the project. I'd
>   suggest using 'Empty Project' as the project type, so you don't have a
>   lot of rubbish auto generated for you that you'll just delete anyway.

Follow these links and choose the way that you like to follow either using `tools` or some `modification` etc..

[How to downgrade solution from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597259/how-to-downgrade-solution-from-visual-studio-2010-to-visual-studio-2005)
[Downgrade C# Project from visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688191/downgrade-c-sharp-project-from-visual-studio-2010-to-visual-studio-2008)
[How to downgrade solution code upgraded to Visual Studio 2010](http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?Topic=How-to-downgrade-solution-code-upgraded-to-Visual-Studio-2010)
[Downgrade a VS 2008 .sln or .csproj to VS 2005](http://www.fsmpi.uni-bayreuth.de/~dun3/archives/downgrade-vs-2008-sln-or-csproj-to-vs-2005-project-solution/139.html)
[How to downgrade from Visual Studio 2010 project to VS 2008 or VS 2005?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsprereleaseannouncements/thread/4345a151-d288-48d6-b7c7-a7c598d0f85e)

> Web Developer 2010 Express is free tool from Microsoft that you can
>   download to work with same version.